# Formula for the KK-theory groups $KK(A, C(S))$

Tags: c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, kk-theory, noncommutative-topology

I am studying $C^*$-algebras and their KK-theory. Let $A$ be a (unital if you wish) $C^*$-algebra and $S$ be a compact Hausdorff space. I am interested in computing the KK-theory groups $KK(A, C(S))$, where $C(S)$ is the $C^*$-algebra of continuous functions on $S$.

I am wondering if there exists a general formula or method for computing $KK(A, C(S))$ for arbitrary $A$ and $S$?

Any help, references, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ satisfies the Universal Coefficient Theorem (UCT) of Rosenberg and Schochet, then the UCT exact sequence splits (unnaturally) giving an isomorphism $KK(A,B) \cong Hom(K_*(A), K_*(B)) \oplus Ext(K_*(A), K_{1-*}(B))$ for any $C^*$-algebra $B$, so essentially $KK(A,B)$ is computable through $K$-theory. Without the UCT I don't think anything general can be said.